# Trying to find a list of drives in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to create a batch file where it will find all the current drives on the computer and set the drives as variables to be called later. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set count=1
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
  set drive!count!=%%a
  set /a count+=1
)

echo There are !count! drives
echo !drive1! rem Change this to do whatever with the variables
echo !drive2!

pause
```

I only showed echoing 2 drives, but, how many you have determines how many variables are created.

Comment: Thank so much it worked i spent 2 hours trying to find it.